# Show loading bar or gif while a php shell_exec runs in background

Tags: php, jquery, loading, gif, shell-exec

I have this php page that rungs its script.
From the index page the user clicks a button and this page, after 10 seconds or so, shows the final result.
I would like to show a progress bar while the user waits.
This is the actual page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>METAR LIRN</title>
  <style>
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .table {
      display: table;
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border: 1px solid #808080;
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table">
    <div>
    <h1>METAR LIRN<h1>
    </div>
    <div>
           <?php
                $output = shell_exec('sh /var/www/html/weather.sh');
                echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
            ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I had a look to other similar posts with no luck...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, here's a quick example:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        /* Just some styles for the bar */
        .loading-bar {
            background: blue;
            width: 300px;
            height: 20px;
            display: none;
        }
            .loading-bar.active {
                display: block;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="myBtn">Execute code!</button>
    <div class="response"></div>
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>

    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        // Handle button click
        $('.myBtn').on('click', function(){
            $('input').val( "" );

            // Inmediatly show your bar
            var $loadingBar = $('.loading-bar');
            $loadingBar.addClass('active');

            // Then execute Ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                method: 'GET'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                // Display response data
                $('div.response').html(data);
            })
            .fail(function(error) {
                // Display error if fails
                $('div.response').html(error);
            })
            .always(function() {
                // Always hide loading bar when finish
                $loadingBar.removeClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
sleep(2);
echo 'OK';
```

Comment: Hi! Actually this page is loaded clicking a simple html button p style="text-align: center;"><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.open('http://raspberrypi.local/weather.php','_blank')">METAR</button></p>

Comment: Well, then you can't implement a loading bar. The PHP code is executed server-side, that means before the page is loaded client-side. You should use Ajax to execute your PHP code. meanwhile you can show your loading bar and remove it when you recive a response: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: yes i tought about that. Unfortunatelly i don't know how to make it work. Can't load the php page, it only shows the loading gif... Can you give me an example?

Comment: Thank you for your example! I added my php page url but it doesn't seem to work... here is my php page code:    <?php
  sleep(2);
  echo 'OK';
  $output = shell_exec('sh /var/www/html/weather.sh');
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
  echo  "error";
  exit;
?>

Comment: The code I use is just an example, just use your code:
<?php $output = shell_exec('sh /var/www/html/weather.sh'); echo "<pre>$output</pre>" ?>. Don't forget the output you print in PHP is going to be the data you recive on your Ajax callback. You can use this data to determine if the response is successful or not. If it still won't work, check your Developer Tools in Chrome (Network tab) to see the PHP response there.

Comment: The page executes the command as i can see from the developer tools beacause there are no errors. Anyway when i execute the code, i see a full blue bar and a Status text above. After a bit the blue bar dissapears and nothing else is there. It just goes back to the original page (OK! - Execute code). What's wrong? I left the original php code in my php page.

Comment: Antonio, that's all my example do. It's up to you to modify it to do whatever you want it to do. The blue bar is just a simple way I used to show you how to show something while the code is executing.

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand now how it works. I only have to find a method to show the result of the php echo in the same page... currently, as i said, it works but nothing is shown.

Comment: Whell, what you print in your PHP will besend as the response data for the Ajax. Check out the done callback, the anonymous function has a 'data' parameter. That's what you want to show. If you wanna, let's say, display the response inside a DIV you can put inside your done callback something like: $('div').html(data);

Comment: Thanks. Where am i supposed to insert this code? $('div').html(data); I am really still a noob in using ajax and jquery :D

Comment: Inside the Ajax callbacks. I edited the example, check out the HTML + jQuery bit.

Comment: Thanks. I see the modification. It works, same as before, but no data is shown :( i can see the result in the Network section (Preview and Response) timing 35.08 s

Comment: It works now using this code: .success(function(data) { $('#response').html(data); And then in body: <div id="response"></div>. Thanks a lot for your patience. I learned a lot today!!